# Error in ahead-of-time compilation using numba in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, numba

I am trying to use the numba Python package to compile a simple function ahead-of-time. I have Python version 3.8.5, numba version 0.51.2 and I code in Jupyter notebook version 6.1.4.

The code I am trying to compile is taken from the [numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html), and is repeated below.

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('my_module')
# Uncomment the following line to print out the compilation steps
#cc.verbose = True

@cc.export('square', 'f8(f8)')
def square(a):
    return a ** 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

It doesn't work, and I get the following error:

```
DistutilsExecError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYCC_MODULE_NAME=my_module -DPYCC_USE_NRT=1 -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\\Users\\erera\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /TcC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\pycc\modulemixin.c /FoC:\Users\erera\AppData\Local\Temp\pycc-build-my_module-gxkjko2h\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\pycc\modulemixin.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

I am not sure what the issue is, and couldn't find much information on it. I should mention that earlier I had the error:

```
Attempted to compile AOT function without the compiler used by `numpy.distutils` present. Cannot find suitable msvc.
```

which disappeared after I installed the Visual Studio Build Tools. Any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a problem related to your installation. This works well on my machine with a regular Python 3.9.9 (not Anaconda) and Numba 0.54.1.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the reply! What installation do you mean? That of the Visual Studio Build Tools or that of Python?

Comment: I do not know which one. You could try to uninstall Visual or force the use of the MinGW tool-chain to check whether this comes from the Visual installation. I am actually surprised pycc could use MSVC...